# Error With Stored Procedure Code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this C# code calling a stored procedure:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Utility.ConnString))
{
    myConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(AddScanLocation_Proc, myConnection))
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationQr", string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocationQr) ? "" : LocationQr);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationNfc", string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocationNfc) ? "" : LocationNfc);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationMachineName", LocationMachineName);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationName", LocationName);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsLastStop", IsLastStop);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", Active);

        IAsyncResult res = myCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

        while (!res.IsCompleted) { }

        int response = myCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(res);

        if (response > 0)
            toReturn = true;
   }
}
```

Every time I execute the code, I get an error telling me

> Procedure or function 'AddScanLocation' expects parameter '@LocationMachineName', which was not supplied.

I have debugged the code for hours and everything is typed correctly, and the variable is not null or empty, but it keeps throwing an error

any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My advice, don't use AddWithValue.

Comment: What's the value and type of @LocationMachineName?

Comment: What is your connection string? Does it include `AttachDBFIleName`? If so, see [this blog post](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/). Also, you say the error references `AddScanLocation` but the code is actually calling `AddScanLocation_Proc` - typo? Or do you have two different objects, one with a useless `_Proc` suffix, that might have different signatures?

Comment: Did you try to set `myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`?

Comment: Could you cut and paste the parameter that is erroring directly from the stored proc into your C# code to avoid any slight spelling mistakes?

Comment: is it because your SQLCommand is "AddScanLocation_Proc" instead of "AddScanLocation"?

Comment: Viper Thank you i didnt even catch that!

Comment: Based on the error message, you are actually calling AddScanLocation did you mess up the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try check first if all your variables (including *LocalMachineName*) has values before call block code for execute your stored procedure.

Checking you code, you posted:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationQr", string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocationQr) ? "" : LocationQr);
```

Why not do the same with *LocalMachineName* too?

PS: Try use test values if the variable *LocalMachineName* doesn't allow null values.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simply: you haven't told ADO.NET that you're executing a **stored procedure**!

Add this line:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(AddScanLocation_Proc, myConnection))
{
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    ......
```

and then everything should work just fine.